# What are the names of the two parts that make up an enum in C#?

Tags: c#, syntax

When discussing the syntax of an enum, I want to know the names of the two halves that make up its syntax.

```
public enum Suits { Diamonds, Clubs, Hearts, Spades}

...

Suits card = Suits.Clubs;
```

My guess is that the `Suits` to the left of the period would be called the enum type and the `Clubs` after the period would be a member. But I didn't see anything official that confirms this.

Comment: Just a second of googling and you would have gotten the anser far mor faster then typing this question.

Comment: @GrantWinney; Even if it is clear, the +1 button also says "shows research effort", which isn't exactly the case here.

Comment: I did search as I normally do, but I didn't pull together a short concise answer as you have given below. Because I didn't find it here It seemed to me a decent question to ask.

Comment: @MakePeaceGreatAgain I did a google, and found this question and answer. The fact that this user did this question, helped me to fulfill your advice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Microsoft wording](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/enum):

> The enum keyword is used to declare an enumeration, a distinct type that consists of a set of named constants called the enumerator list.

So `Suits` is the *type name*, `Diamonds, Clubs, Hearts, Spades` is the *enumeration list* and `Clubs` is a *named constant*. Its *value* is 1.

> By default, the first enumerator has the value 0, [...]

So the named constants are also called *enumerator*.

Answer (score 2):

According to the [Official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/enum) you could call:

- Suits: The Enumeration or Enumerator list.
- Clubs: An Enumerator.

> The enum keyword is used to declare an enumeration, a distinct type
>   that consists of a set of named constants called the enumerator list.
>
> By default, the first enumerator has the value 0, and the value of
>   each successive enumerator is increased by 1. For example, in the
>   following enumeration, Sat is 0, Sun is 1, Mon is 2, and so forth.